# How to make a dictionary from a text file with many elements?

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I'm trying to make a dictionary for the text file Subscrition_Info.txt. the text file looks like this:

[image]

I need to make it into a dictionary named subscriptions, but I don't know how to because the list has more then 2 values.

Any ideas of how to solve this issue?

I have tried:

[image]
but the code doesn't work and the error is :

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output? Also please never post code as images, simply copy/paste your code into the question and format it as code. If you need any help, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You are trying to unpack 4 values (CustID, SubType, Start, End) into 2 variables (`key, val`). Your current aproach goes along the wrong axis.

Answer (score 0):

If the items you want are the first two from each row, you can store those to `key` & `val` and discard the remaining items with the following:

```
key,val,*_ = line.split(',')
```